# How to add product in scipio E-commerce?

Tags: e-commerce, erp, ofbiz

I added product in scipioerp but it is not displayed in scipio E-commerce.
I have added poduct's price,image,category,inventory but still not shown on e-commerce.
Is there any configuration I am missing ?

Would really appreciate if somebody could point towards right direction.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There had been a bug in the solr configuration, which prevented the synchronisation through events such as adding new products. The bug has been fixed in the master branch since. More details about the cause are avaialble on the community forum :).